# Can I do push ups being a vertigo patient?

Tags: push-ups

Can a person with Benign Paroxysmal Positional Vertigo do push ups,does doing more push ups increases vertigo attaks?

Comment: Ask your doctor.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find exercise induced vertigo specific to push ups. However,
If someone has vestibular—inner ear— disorders , he/she often experiences problems with balance and position or movement-related dizziness.

In your case, you have to identify the movements that cause the dizziness, he/she can begin an exercise program to repeat those movements—a concept that seems contradictory. In order to get rid of his/her dizziness, you have to repeat the movements that make him/her dizzy. It is important that you repeat them at least five times in a row and do them twice a day. If you find there are five different movements that make you dizzy, pick two to work on at a time. Once you no longer experience dizziness in response to these movements, add two more. Don’t try to do exercises for more than two movements at a time.

[vertigo](http://vestibular.org/sites/default/files/page_files/Vestibular%20Rehabilitation_0.pdf)